Not able to connect to ActiveMQ 6.x with SSL client certificate and WITHOUT SASL
I have activemq classic 6.x version. I am trying to disable SASL resulting in the consumers and publishers to connect using only the SSL certificates. But it is not working. During my configuration attempts and connection attempts from consumer, the logs in consumer show that server is offering SASL [PLAIN, ANONYMOUS].
I did not find anything in activemq documentation. The documentation simply lists down the login.config file.

Target


Disable SASL
Enable only ssl client auth


Steps Performed


Create trust store with "Intermediate CA" and "Root CA" of the client certificate
Configure transport connector in bin/activemq.xml
Configure login.config
Configure users.properties
Configure groups.properties

COnfigurations in steps section are as follows in the same order as above
2. bin/active.xml
Transport Connector
<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?transport.closeAsync=false&amp;needClientAuth=true&amp;wantClientAuth=true"/>
<transportConnector name="amqps" uri="amqp+ssl://0.0.0.0:5673?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;needClientAuth=true"/>

Note: needClientAuth=true enable certificate based authentication at Transport Layer i.e. "OSI Layer 4"

Configure login.config

activemq{
    
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule sufficient
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group="groups.properties";
        
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.TextFileCertificateLoginModule required
        debug=true
        reload=true
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.user="cert-users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.group="groups.properties";
};

Note: TextFileCertificateLoginModule enables certificate based authentication at Application Layer i.e. "OSI Layer 7"
If this is not enabled then SASL plain is used.
I tried changing this file to only TextFileCertificateLoginModule but no success
activemq{
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.TextFileCertificateLoginModule required
        debug=true
        reload=true
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.user="cert-users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.group="groups.properties";
};


User.properties and cert-users.properties
Add Certificate DN details

admin=adminpassword
usr-data-consumer=CN=text-cert-client-adjacent-system


groups.properties

admins=admin,usr-data-consumer


What client library are you using to connect?

I have tried with 3 Spring AMQP, Apache QPID JMS, Apache QPID Proton

I have found the answer and wrote clean implementation with possible scenarios. Its available on Medium
Solution Link
A short description and configuration of the solution is as follows. Main catch here is to configure the CN names carefully in users.properties file.
Login.config file
cert-login{ 
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.TextFileCertificateLoginModule required
        debug=true
        reload=true
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.user="cert-users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.group="groups.properties";
};

Users.properties file
consumer1user=CN=consumer-cert-1, OU=ABC, O=ORGMY, L=PK, ST=LAHORE, C=PK

Activemq.xml file
 <plugins>
  <jaasCertificateAuthenticationPlugin configuration="cert-login"/>
  <!--jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq"/-->
 </plugins>


In medium i have writtn solution for the issues that popup once you disable jaasAuthenticationPlugin. Which is kind of irrelevant to the subject question here. Moreover, the possible CN values and usage of regex in users.properties file to perform wild card matches of CN

